# how to integrate facebook(like),twitter,google plus(bubble button) android app

Tags: android

I want to integrate facebook(like),twitter,google plus(bubble button) into my android app, which is developed using Android, so that I can post my application URL to there status. I referred a lot of links and nothing is working for me.

Comment: Please be a bit more specific. What exactly did you tried first? Btw, you need to handle all of these individually. So for example you can start with facebook. They have a nice API, downloadable example code, good documentation, etc. But to help you first we need to know what we you tried first?

Comment: I want to post my application URL to user wall on Google+. I did same thing in facebook its working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't inject social plugins that you expect. When you are in a native app, assume that you run an html file in your local, because of that reason, this plugins will not run too.
You have to use their SDK'